# jQuery Search for an element within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and need help on searching for user-typed element within a table.   I wrote this in JS, but have a problem writing in using jQuery.

When the element is found, the other rows in the table with the same class name should be visible and other rows should be hidden:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    search(".site-table", "#recordInput");
    console.log("Document is ready");
    }
);

function search(search_table, search_field)
{

    // Searching for an item specified in search_field within a table


    $(search_field).on("keyup", function() 
    {
        var target_text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        //Hide everything first
        $(search_table).find('tr').addClass(".hidden");

        $(search_table).find('tr').each(function(index, element){
            // For each row, find out if the row has the target_text in it
            $element:contains($target_text).each(function(index, element){
                $(element).removeClass(".hidden");
            });

            // for each row with the target text in it, find other rows with this rows class name in their class name and show them.  Any other row should be hidden



    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:

So, here is the editted code after the comments.  I still cannot get it working:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
search(".site-table", "#recordInput");
console.log("Document is ready");
}
```

);

```
function search($search_table, $search_field)
{
    console.log("Starting to search...");

    $($search_field).on("keyup", function() 
    {
        // Heighlight the search field 
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');

        $search_text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        // 1st method:
        $search_result = $($search_table).find('tbody tr').text().toLowerCase().indexOf($search_text > -1);  // Does not work!  Nothing is found when there is a match
        console.log("Search Result: ", $search_result);


        // 2nd method:
        $($search_table).find('tr').each(function(index, element){
            // For each row, toggle the hidden class if the row contains the search text
            $(this).toggleClass('hidden', $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($search_text > -1));
        });

        // 3rd method:
        var found = $($search_table).find('tbody tr').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == $search_text;  
        });

        console.log("found: ", found);    
    });
}
```

None of these methods works!  What am I doing wrong in each method?

Comment: `$element:contains`  colon isn't a valid character there.  Also `$element` is not defined

Comment: `$(element).removeClass(".hidden");`  Remove class takes a class, not a selector.  Remove the period. Same with `.addClass(".hidden");`, remove the period

Comment: `$target_text` is also not defined.

Comment: $('#list').find('a.box');  You select the table Id and that's the scope, after that you can search for the element you want

Comment: Can you explain or give an example of how these associated classes work? For example, if a row has multiple classes, how do you know which to look for in the other rows? Or is it all of them? If you're relying on each row only having one class, you should be using something like a `data` attribute instead, otherwise adding classes would have feature-breaking implications. Consider including some example HTML in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about using the `indexOf`. What you must put between the parentheses is only the searching text and  `> -1` must be out. See this sample:

```js
var its_ok = $('div').first().html().indexOf('b') >  -1
console.log('first one: ', its_ok)

var its_not_ok = $('div').first().html().indexOf('b' >  -1)
console.log('second one: ', its_not_ok)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abcd</div>
```

What you have done is the second one that is not true way of using the `indexOf`.